# update nested state object with array inside

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setstate

I am having trouble updating my state object that has an array of objects inside. There are few things that I have tried but none of them worked. Here is an example of my state object. With the example below, I want to update the values for test and test2 depending on whatever the user types in input field. Can someone guide me in the right direction. Thank you!

```
this.state = {
   someProperty: {
      someOtherProperty: [
          object in array: {
             test: true,
             test2: false
          },
          object in array: {
             test: true
             test2: false
          }
          ..
      ]
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

My attempt on updating the value inside the object is as follows:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    someProperty: {
        ...prevState.someProperty,
        someOtherProperty: [
            ...prevState.someProperty.someOtherProperty, 
            test: false
        ]
    }
}))
```

Comment: would you like to update all item in `someOtherProperty` as `test: false`

Comment: No. I would like specific one. For example, if they want to update the first object in someOtherProperty as test: false then the other object shouldn't get updated. I have access to the index but not sure how to incorporate that into the setSate.

Comment: you  cannot put `test: false` directly, because `someOtherProperty` is an array of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array `latestSomeOtherProperty`, update the wanted index and then;

```
const latestSomeOtherProperty = someOtherProperty.map(prop=>{...prop, test: false}); // it updates all but you can put condition here

this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    someProperty: {
        ...prevState.someProperty,
        someOtherProperty: [
            ...latestSomeOtherProperty
        ]
    }
}))
```

Comment: Ok, I think that can work. But is there no direct way to update the property using the spread operator?

Comment: It is an array you need to update the correct item, so need to loop it to find and update. Otherwise you will add a new item into the array

Comment: Ok great. I just went with that approach. Before setting the state, I am just looping thru that array and updating that specific value.